# Ionic Error, Unable to Verify First Certificate

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic3, npm-install

I am going to develop my first application on Ionic and I installed nodeJS on my Windows 10 and using npm command, I am installing ionic using command

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

It was installed, now when I am going to create a project using command,

```
ionic start projectName blank
```

It shows directory created and then shows error as

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate

at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1062:38)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:586:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38)
```

I tried and searched a lot with different commands like

```
npm config set strict-ssl false

npm config set https-proxy https://github.com
```

but not works and same error occurs.

Please help if you have faced this error or you can.

Versions of the packages are as below:

npm version: 3.10.8

node version: 7.0.0

ionic cli version: 4.1.2

Cordova version: 8.0.0

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by "It shows directory created and then shows error"
please elaborate and be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You might be behind some proxy.
Please follow this link https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/using-a-proxy

Or
run the below command as an Administrator in your command Prompt with the proper proxy address:
$ ionic config set -g proxy http://proxy.example.com:8888